# Check if a MongoDB value exists before inserting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, twilio

I'm making a MEAN app w/ Twilio that allows people to sign an online petition by texting their name to the app. People should be able to sign the petition only once. I plan on ensuring this by allowing only one signature per phone number.

Every time the petition is signed a Mongo object like this will be created:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5c5a47ae8f04f9148f43b033"),          
  "name" : "John Doe", 
  "number" : "+18373987466", 
  "date" : "2/5/19" 
}
```

I've already turned the `number` field into a **unique index**, so there can be only signature per phone number.

The problem I'm coming across is what to do when someone tries to sign the petition multiple times. I want to intercept their attempt and send them a message saying that they've already signed the petition.

As I see it I have two options:

**OPTION #1**
Query the database to see if the same number has already been entered.

This seems like something that should be easy but I just can't figure out how to do it.

```
var number = '+18373987466';
if(collection.find({"number":number}) {
  twiml.message("You have already signed the petition");
}
```

My thinking here is that`collection.find({"number":number})` would return `true` if it found an entry with the same number. However, it returns the entire Mongo cursor.

**OPTION #2**
Since `number` is a unique index, Mongo will throw an error if another object is created with the same value. I could intercept the error that is thrown and send a message to the user afterwards.

My first question with this approach is: is it good software design to knowingly allow your app to throw an error?

I tried this approach with a `try/catch` block but the error that was thrown crashed the app immediately.

```
try {
  collection.insertOne(
    {name : name, number : number, date: dateSigned}, 
    function(error, result) {
      console.log(`${name} has been added to the database`);
  });
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

Is this not the correct way to 'catch' an error and prevent it from crashing the app?

Comment: Have you tried using mongoose? It's usually my choice when I work with node.js and mongodb. And as it provides Schemas a unique field is pretty simple then.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

This should clarify things a little. The documentation is actually pretty good

Comment: My database needs for this app are so simple that Mongoose seemed like overkill.

Answer (score 3):

**Option #1**

The described behavior is correct, MongoDB will return a cursor if you use `collection.find()`. You could use [collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count). But since you are only interested if there is already at least one value, you can just call `cursor.limit(1)`.

```
if (collection.find({"number":number}).limit(1).length === 1) 
   twiml.message("You have already signed the petition");
```

**Option #2**

> Is it good software design to knowingly allow your app to throw an
>   error?

No. I consider this bad design. If the entry already exists I would not consider it an error but a case that needs special treatment. If you use `catch()` you would still need to check what kind of error it is to send the correct message to the user.
Imagine your database is not reachable therefore you can't insert a new value this would be a (real) error and you should catch() it.

Comment: The conditional statement didn't work because .limit(1) returns a Mongo cursor, not a number. Your suggestion did steer me in the right direction though. I just switched count() and limit() around since count() returns a number and provides a callback.

Comment: You are right, you can simply use db.collection.find(<query>).limit(1). Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = '+18373987466';
result = collection.find_one({"number":number}) 
if result is not None:
    twiml.message("You have already signed the petition");
```